# Passing wrapper class data from vf to the component

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

how can i pass wrapper class data from vf page to component and show it in the data table or pageblock table

I have the following code which creates the wrapper object.

```
    public class yourcontroller 
{
    public class dataWrapper
    {
        public string attn {get;set;}
        public string Product{get;set;}
        .....
        //other fields in the table
    }

public List<dataWrapper> dataContent {get;set;} 




        public void PopulateData()
        {
            dataContent = new List<dataWrapper>();

            List<cc_ST_OrderConfigData__c > custom1List =[select id,Attn__c,Forwarder__c,Branch_address__c,Currency__c,AB_CODE__c,IBAN__c,Shipper__c,Country__c,Swiftcode__c,Item__r.id from cc_ST_OrderConfigData__c ];
            List<ccrz__E_OrderItem__c];> custom2List = [Select id,Order__r.id,Product__r.id, Product__r.SKU__c,Product_Name__c,Quantity__c,Total_Price_c, Price__c,ItemTotal__c FROM ccrz__E_OrderItem__c];

            Map<String,cc_ST_OrderConfigData__c> custom1Map = new Map<String,cc_ST_OrderConfigData__c>();
            for (cc_ST_OrderConfigData__c c : custom1List)
            {
                if (!custom1Map.contansKey(c.Item__r.id))
                {
                    custom1Map.put(c.Item__r.Id,c);
                }
            }

            for (ccrz__E_OrderItem__c&nbsp;c : custom1List)
            {
                if (custom1Map.containsKey(c.Product__r.id))
                {
                    dataWrapper data = new dataWrapper();
                    cc_ST_OrderConfigData__c cust1 = custom1Map.get(c.Product__r.Id);
                    data.attn = cust1.attn__c;
                    data.product = c.product__r.id;
                    .......
                    //populate other fields

                    dataContent.add(data);
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

I need to pass this  data from vf page to vf component

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" title="Order-Line Items" tabStyle="ccrz__E_Order__c" renderAs="pdf" extensions="yourcontroller"  showHeader="false">
    <c:MyComponent  DataTable="{!dataContent}" />
</apex:page>
```

​​​​​​​

```
<apex:component>
    <apex:attribute name="DataTable" description="wrapper class of two table" type="List" />
    {!DataTable[0].product} <!-- I am getting value here -->
<apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:pageBlockTable id="tbl" value="{!DataTable}" var="Odr" border="1px"  width="100%" align="centre">
            <apex:column headerValue="attn"  value="{!Odr.attn}"/> 
            <apex:column headerValue="product" value="{!Odr.product}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable> 
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:component>
```

I am getting following error on developer console
Unknown property **'Object.attn'** 
Unknown property '**Object.product'** for page block table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your apex:attribute type must match the data type of variable that you pass into the component.
And the type does not recognise inner class, so you need to define the wrapper class as a top-level class.

```java
<apex:attribute name="DataTable" description="wrapper class of two table" type="dataWrapper[]" />
```